# Storing binary files in sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing an mvc/sql server application that needs to associate documents (word, pdf, excel, etc) with records in the database (supporting sql server 2005).  The consensus is it's best to keep the files in the file system and only save a path/reference to the file in the database.  However, in my scenario, an audit trail is extremely important.  We already have a framework in place to record audit information whenever a change is made in the system so it would be nice to use the database to store documents as well.  If the documents were stored in their own table with a FK to the related record would performance become an issue?  I'm aware of the potential problems with backups/restores but would db performance start to degrade at some point if the document tables became very large?  If it makes any difference I would never expect this system to need to service anywhere near 100 concurrent requests, maybe tens of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the files as blob in database will increase the size of the db and will definitely affect the backups which you know and is true.

There are many things of consideration whether the db and code server are same.

Because it happens to be code server requests and gets data from db server and then from code server to client.

If the file sizes are too large I would say go for the file system and save file paths in db.

Else you can keep the files as blog in db, it will definitely be more secure, as well as safe from virus, etc.

Comment: So would storing a large number of blobs affect the over all performance of the db server?